# Include all files from a folder in MSI

Tags: visual-studio, wix, wix3.7

How can I to include all files from source folder and deploy them into a target folder during installation. I have multiple images in a folder and i want all of them to be included in msi automatically rather than including all of them separately using `<File>` element.

Comment: read about heat in the wix tutorial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to Read about HEAT in the wix installer tutorial, 
http://wix.tramontana.co.hu/

```
"%WIX%\bin\heat.exe" dir "$(SolutionDir)bin\Release -out Release.wxs"
```

this is the type of pre-build event you will need to define in order to harvest a directory.